TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null while creating adapter
So I am creating a node application and implementing io redis for socket emmiter. I am creating adapter but getting error.
class ShardedRedisAdapter extends socket_io_adapter_1.ClusterAdapter {
^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
import express, { Application } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import RequestHandler from "./api";
import "reflect-metadata";
import "es6-shim";
import listEndpoints from "express-list-endpoints";
import "./db.config";
import { globalErrorHandler } from "./middlewares/Error";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { createAdapter } from "@socket.io/redis-adapter";
import { Redis } from "ioredis";

const app: Application = express();

const CorsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: true,
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"],
};
app.use(cors(CorsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

RequestHandler(app);
app.use(globalErrorHandler);
console.log(listEndpoints(app as express.Express));

export const httpServer = createServer(app);

const pubClient = new Redis(6379, "localhost", {
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
});

const subClient = new Redis(6379, "localhost", {
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
});

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  adapter: createAdapter(pubClient, subClient),
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected");
  });
});

httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 9001, () => {
  console.log(`️ Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT || 9001}`);
});


I was trying to connect ioredis with my application to emit events.
This is my docker compose file
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: server-postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
  redis:
    image: redis/redis-stack
    container_name: server-redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${REDIS_PORT}:6379
      - ${REDISINSIGHT_PORT}:8001
    environment:
      - REDIS_ARGS=--requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - redis:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis
  server:
    image: server-dev
    build:
      context: .
      target: server-dev
      args:
        - PORT:${PORT}
    container_name: server-dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/server/
volumes:
  pgadmin-data:
  postgres:
    name: server-postgres
  pgadmin:
    name: pgadmin-data
  redis:
    name: server-redis
networks:
  default:
    name: server


